# Discord Bot does not work with while-loop

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def start():
    while True:
        await switch()
        time.sleep(1)

async def switch():
    for i in range(len(aktiv)):
        print(list[i])
        print(aktiv[i])
        if list[i].voice != None:
            if aktiv[i] == False:
                aktiv[i] = True
                print('Erkannt')
                await music(list[i], song)
            else:
                pass
        else:
            aktiv[i] = False
```

Bot was written to play Music when a Player joined a voice Channel
I check if the Player is new in the channel using the code.
But when the loop is running it seems like it can't detect, when a user.voice changes.
It only takes the very first input.
Does somebody have a solution how i can test if a person is new in a Channel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65385279/check-if-user-is-in-a-voice-channel-discord-py This seems to be what you are asking for.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `time.sleep` which is a blocking function, (for more info read [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)), use `asyncio.sleep` instead

```py
import asyncio

async def start():
    while True:
        await switch()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my day

Comment: no worries, remember to accept the answer;)